# Is there a way to increase your inventory slots?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

From what I see, the first 4 slots are for equipment and other 8 slots are for items.

Now I want to know if there is a way to increase the amount of inventory slots, because 8 slots is really low.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to increase your inventory size beyond the 8 slots.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realm_of_the_Mad_God:

> A character's inventory capacity is very limited as the player can store 8 items on a character (beyond what the character has equipped), plus a free private vault chest in the nexus which stores items across deaths/characters.

Players start with 1 free vault and can purchase more vault chests. Items in these chests are account-based so any items in the vault can be used to equip a new character.

http://realmofthemadgod.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nexus says:

> Each chest can hold eight items; any items left on the floor will disappear when you leave your Vault. You get one vault to start off with, but the rest you must pay for using the money in the game.

Comment: Well that just sucks,thx.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could buy a backpack. It is consumed on use, and doubles inventory space.

Comment: When did they add this? That's a huge improvement! Can you tell us how to get a backpack?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can either buy a backpack which adds 8 more spaces, by more vaults. Backpacks are found in the nexus stores. If you can't find one go here. https://www.realmeye.com/items/misc Or you should pick up less stuff and only pick up the best stuff like pots. If you have a item you can wear, you should put it on. The best way is to make 4 extra fake accounts. 1 for items for classes that wear hides, one for items for classes that wears heavy armour, one for items for classes that wear robes, and one for rings, pots, and other stuff. You have 8 spaces in your inventory, 8 spaces in your vault, and maybe if you have luck, you can wear one of your stuff. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make another account and store your stuff there.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by the -1. Although it sounds like your suggestion would work (I've never played Mad God, but mules are common in RPGs), please be aware that Arqade promotes fun and legal solutions to players' questions, and members are intolerant of solutions involving bots, mules, hack, mods and in general suggestions that may mar the gaming experience for players that don't employ these tactics. For a related discussion, please see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/933/20893

Comment: In the end, how people downvote can be based on their opinions and expectations.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to increase the inventory slots. However, you effectively get a "free" chest per character; you can just use those slots to store your excess items.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a backpack (which doubles your inventory space) when you spawn at nexus, you should see a backpack.

Answer (score -1):

If you want more money, you can make a mule account. One problem with that, is that you can't transfer the gold over to your main account. Although, you can buy what you want with the 50 gold and then trade it to your main account.